# Play 2.5 java.lang.NullPointerException in Form

Tags: playframework, form-submit, playframework-2.5

I've this small application, I just want to create a simple form and store the user input, however every time I try to run the application I get a **java.lang.NullPointerException**, it tells me the error is in the index method in the controller class, when declaring the form in definitionForm

Here is my controller

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {
@Inject 
public static FormFactory formFactory;

public Result index() {
    Form<Definition> definitionForm = formFactory.form(Definition.class);
    return ok(index.render(definitionForm,"Your new application is ready."));
}
public Result submit(){
    Form<Definition> definitionForm = formFactory.form(Definition.class).bindFromRequest();
    Definition definition=definitionForm.get();
    definition.save();
    return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());

}}
```

The model

```
@Entity
public class Definition extends Model {
@Id
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String name;

public String definition;
public String category;
public static final Model.Find<Long,Definition> find = new Model.Find<Long,Definition>(){};
  }
```

And here are the errors

```
    ! @6pnmighcp - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at controllers.HomeController.index(HomeController.java:27)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:157)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:157)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:73)
    at play.http.HttpRequestHandler$1.call(HttpRequestHandler.java:54)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
```

I have

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

in my application conf and the Play Ebean plugin enabled, I'm not really sure what the issue is.

Comment: Try to remove static when injecting FormFactory, it seems that FormFactory is not injected at all.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: did you ever resolve the null pointer issue with the `MailerClient`, I have the same error, using `@Inject MailerClient mailerclient` which is added to my controller, not static prefix, yet this null pointer error persists. p.s. `Play 2.6.x`

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this as an answer in case somebody stumbles upon (Tijkijiki already stated it in the comment): *the `FormFactory` field shouldn't be static*.

**More information:**

The Play 2.5.x documentation states it:

> To wrap a class you have to inject a play.data.FormFactory into your Controller which then allows you to create the form:
>
> Form userForm = formFactory.form(User.class);

So the correct way to inject the `FormFactory` into the controller is like this:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    @Inject FormFactory formFactory;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to remove the `static` as well, and still doesn't work for me.